# PHP Fatal error when trying to add a DateInterval to a DateTime object

Tags: php, datetime, addition, dateinterval

What am I doing wrong here?

PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function add() on a non-object in

```
    $rndM = rand(48,51);
    $rndS = rand(1,59);
    $ts = new DateTime($krow['GLSTRT']);
    $tsd = $ts->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $tsup = 'PT'.$rndM.'i'.$rndS.'s';
    $lamDate= $tsd->add(new DateInterval('\''.$tsup.'\''));
```

`$krow['GLSTRT']` is a data value from MSSQL.

At first I was getting format errors with the `add(new DateInterval)`.

I added in the format line, which resolved the format error and now the `add(new DateInterval)` is throwing the error at the beginning of this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

:banghead:  Thank you guys.  This is what I get for rushing a fix.  Here's the final product.

```
    $ts = new DateTime($krow['GLSTRT']);
    $intervalString = 'PT' . $rndM . 'M' . $rndS . 'S';
    $ts ->add(new DateInterval($intervalString));
    $lamDate = $ts->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 2):

A few things:

- `format()` returns a string, so you cannot use `add()` on the result as it is not an object. You need `$ts->add()` instead.
- You should check the right syntax for the `DateInterval` constructor; at the very least you need to get rid of the quotes around your string.
- When you use the `add()` method, you modify your object, so assigning it to another variable is pointless unless you clone it first. Now both `$ts` (see my first point) and `$lamDate` will reference the same object.

Answer (score 1):

- The `DateTime->format()` has the following method signature:

  `public string format ( string $format )`. It returns a string.
- You don't need to reassign the DataTime object to work with it.

---

I've modified the order of the code and the variable names a little bit to make things clear:

```
// create new datetime object and return formatted date
$date = new DateTime($krow['GLSTRT']);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n";

// define interval string and create a new DateInterval object
$rndM = rand(48,51);
$rndS = rand(1,59);
$intervalString = 'PT' . $rndM . 'i' . $rndS . 's';
$intervalObject = new DateInterval($intervalString); 

// add interval to date object  
$date ->add($intervalObject); 

// return the modified value formatted  
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n";
```